# The best Stack Exchange site for wireless communications questions

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

What is the best Stack Exchange site that answers questions regarding digital communications and wireless communications, and questions regarding OFDM, CDMA, LTE, etc.?

Comment: You could take a look to dsp.stackexchange.com and check if your questions would fit there.

Comment: Could you be more specific?  Are there particular aspects that interest you?  I know the topic is general excepted on both [EE.SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) and [Engr.SE](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/) but I do not participate much in either site so I can't tell you much beyond that.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I'm on both and find Engr.SE is filled with more physicial engineering than technical questions. But EE.SE has alwasy been my goto for wireless communication so :thumbsup: for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

This topic has been on Area51 three times in the past and has never gotten enough traction. Mostly because there is several overlaping sites already handling these topics.

The fine folks on [EE.SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com) are more than willing to answer questions about wireless communication technology and theory.

While the guys over on [Sec.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com) can answer more about the encryption, Authorization/Athentication/Accounting, and general security with wireless communication.

Finally [NetworkEngineering](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com) is the best place to follow up for any network related questions.

Comment: EE.SE kicked me out once. Thanks for the rest of suggestions.

Comment: @Tyrone: There is also the *[Amateur Radio](http://ham.stackexchange.com/tour)* Stack Exchange site. Sample: *[Can tropospheric scatter effect be used by 802.11 links?](http://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/1497)*

Comment: ee.se blocked my question

Answer (score 3):

I am supporting the [creation of a Telecommunications QA on StackExchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/104688/telecommunications).

I know this has been proposed several times but I truly believe there is an audience. The main challenge I face is that people interested in this idea do not know Stack Exchange and find it complicated to register on Area 51, verify the email, support and vote for the site (it is not that straightforward).

See here to support it: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/104688/telecommunications

Comment: Unfortunately, this proposal has been deleted due to insufficient activity. I strongly support the idea.